# Синонім до слова „підробляти“ в значенні „мати додаткову роботу“

Tags: синоніми, омоніми

Сьогодні в [статті DW](http://www.dw.com/uk/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%83/a-39999693) натрапив на таке речення:

> Кожен четвертий депутат Бундестагу підробляє паралельно до роботи в німецькому парламенті.

І першою думкою було, що депутати щось фальшують.

Проблема в тому, що обидвом словам *підробка* (фальшування) й *підробіток* (додатковий заробіток) відповідає дієслово *підробляти*.

Чи існує синонім до цього слова в значенні „мати додаткову роботу“, який не так просто переплутати з незаконними діями?

Comment: На мою думку, додатковим індикатором для розуміння значення (окрім контексту), слугує наявність додатка, що вказує на перехідність/неперехідність дієслова. **Підробляти** у значенні  *виготовляти підробку* - дієслово перехідне, потребує додатку, на відміну від значення *мати додаткову роботу*. Це зазначено і в [статті  СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidrobljaty). Це ж стосується і дієслова **приробляти**, яке пропонує у своїй відповіді @Follower.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

— [Словник української мови в 11 томах](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85)

- [Прироб**і**ток](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryrobitok), тку, *чол*. Додатковий заробіток. *Для Івана Корнійовича було ясно, що син живе не на свої шістсот, що він має ще приробіток поверх того* ([Іван Сенченко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Опов., 1959, 110); *За існуючих умов оплати заробіток робітника-відрядника складається, в основному, з трьох частин: оплати за тарифом, премії і відрядного приробітку за перевиконання норм* ([Комуніст України](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?&I21DBN=EIU&P21DBN=EIU&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=eiu_all&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=TRN=&S21COLORTERMS=0&S21STR=Bilshovyk_Ukrainy), 11, 1965, 19).

---

— [Словник української мови в 11 томах](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85)
— [Московсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр.](http://r2u.org.ua/html/krym_details.html) ([Агатангел Кримський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [Сергій Єфремов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%84%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))
— [Московсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р.](http://r2u.org.ua/html/dorosh_pered.html) (М. Дорошенко, [Микола Станиславський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0), [Володимир Страшкевич](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))

- [Приробл**я**ти](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8), **я**ю, **я**єш *і* [прир**о**блювати](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), юю, юєш, *недок*., прироб**и**ти, робл**ю**, роб**и**ш; *мн*. прир**о**блять: *док*., *перех*.

  1. Прикріплювати, приєднувати що-небудь до чогось, відповідно пристосовуючи; прилаштовувати. *Петро Михайлович взяв у руки олівець і почав поясняти план: — Оце має бути рама, або фюзеляж... Чуєте: фю-зе-ляж... До нього прироблюють всі інші частини аероплана* ([Степан Васильченко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1959, 228); *Обмажу на зиму хлів, обкладу соломою, прироблю двері...* ([Остап Вишня](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF_%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F), I, 1956, 78); *До її дверей Семен Трохимович приробив защіпку, і Віра, коли заходить до кімнати, замикається* ([Ярослав Гримайло](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Син.., 1950, 104);
     ／ Прибудовувати що-небудь до чогось. *Денис он цього року до хати приробив ще другу половину — з великою світлицею та з кімнатою* ([Борис Грінченко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1963, 313); *— Дасть бог, поженимо дітей, то я для Карпа прироблю хату через сіни, — сказав Кайдаш, виходячи за ворота* ([Нечуй-Левицький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1956, 282);
     ／  Виготовляти, створювати що-небудь на додаток до чогось. *Я знайшов перекладчика [перекладача] своєї статті, приробив вступ про «два панславізми»* ([Михайло Драгоманов](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1970, 533).
  2. *розм.* Працюючи, примножувати майно, прибутки; збагачувати. *Помираючи, старий Сахно казав до своїх дітей: «Сутуж тепер і на землю і на гроші. Сутуж, діти. Оце, що маю, візьміть та приробляйте»* (Іван Микитенко, II, 1957, 75); *Вони [сім'я Чумаків] не тільки для себе жили та дбали, а й для держави щось приробляли* ([Василь Кучер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Прощай.., 1957, 360); Лук'ян умів вести велике господарство і навіть встиг за короткий час дещо приробити до батьківського (Арсен Іщук, Вербівчани, 1961, 17).
  3. *розм.* Заробляти, *перев*. понад основний заробіток. *[Півень:] Прироби, то й матимеш. Мені треба, то я роблю...* ([Іван Микитенко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), I, 1957, 39); *— Я хотів приробити грошей, щоб хоч відкупити батьків ґрунт у долині та стягтися на сяку-таку халупу* ([Степан Чорнобривець](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Визволення, 1949, 71); *Довги.. такі, що й сто літ живи, то стільки не приробиш* ([Лесь Мартович](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Тв., 1954, 86).

— [Словарь української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) ([Борис Грінченко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))

- Приробляти, л**я**ю, єш, *сов. в*. приробити, бл**ю**, биш, *гл*.

  1. Придѣлывать, придѣлать. *Чортинята миттю приробили йому довгенькі крила*. Стор. МПр. 47.
  2. Зарабатывать, заработать. Г. Барв. 371. *Два годи ходив по Дону, приробив трохи грошей*. Г. Барв. 175. *Позичив грошей та й приробив собі, як той, що талант дано йому, що у євангелії читають.* Камен. у.

---

— [Паралельний корпус](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html) · [Інституту московської мови](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%92._%D0%92._%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D) імені [Віктора Віноградова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

- *У мене є зачепки, чотири тьолки в бікіні, працюють добу через дві, частіше не можуть — [підпрацьовують](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mysent=&mysize=9383923&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&mycorp=(lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22)&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%EE%E4%F0%E0%E1%E0%F2%FB%E2%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&flags1=&sem1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&flags2=&sem2=&docid=1914) у палаці піонерів.* [[Сергій Жадан](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). [Гімн демократичної молоді](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96) (2006)]

---

— Практичний словник синонімів української мови ([Святослав Караванський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87))

- Підробляти, *([на стороні](http://sum.in.ua/s/storona))* [підзаробляти](http://zosh6.at.ua/praktichnij_slovnik_sinonimiv_ukrajinskoji_movi.pdf).